# stackable items and how to change their quantity in order to display using interpolated data?

Tags: python, text, string-interpolation, renpy

I'm not very experienced, and I have a lovely working inventory that I've built in renpy/python. I have run into some struggles when trying to make my items stackable. I have been trying to get my class item object to have an editable variable/integer I'm not sure if it's a syntax I'm looking for, or if I need to arrange my classes differently, and if so, how? Previously, the inventory would just add an identical item (and icon) into my display screen. This is what I want to display in my designated text:

```
class item(object):
        def __init__(self, name, img, himg, THIS THING):
            self.name = name
            self.img = img
            self.himg = himg
            self.THIS THING = THIS THING
```

The closest I have come without getting a 'name is not defined' error despite the name clearly being defined or some kind of garbled "%item.amountd" text appearing in my field instead is this:

```
label start:
     show screen inventory
     pause
     "adding another item"
     $ backpack.add_item(popcorn)
     jump start

return



default popcorn = item("popcorn", "inventory/ragepop_idle.png", "inventory/ragepop_hover.png", 0)
default money = 50
default backpack = container()
default inv = []



######screen
screen inventory():
    zorder 2
    add "images/inventory/inventorybg.png"
    modal True
    text "Money: [money]0" xpos 310 ypos 60 color("#FFFFFF")

    hbox:
        xpos 298 ypos 113
        spacing 7
        xmaximum 695
        box_wrap True
        for thing in backpack.inv:
            imagebutton idle thing.item.img hover thing.item.himg action Null
            text "{b}[thing.item.amt]{/b}" size 20 color("#FFFFFF") xoffset -30 yoffset 5


    imagebutton:
        idle "inventory/invpois.png"
        hover "inventory/invpois2.png"
        focus_mask True
        action Hide("inventory")

##amt is what I settled on for the THIS THING
init python:
    class item(object):
        def __init__(self, name, img, himg, amt):
            self.name = name
            self.img = img
            self.himg = himg
            self.amt = amt

    class invitem(object):
        def __init__(self, item, amount):
            self.item = item
            self.amount = amount


    class container(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.inv = []


## Disregard these add/remove methods as I have to change these once I figure out how to $ amt+=1
##As they stand now, they serve to put the icon in the inventory the old unstackable way.

        def add_item(self, item, amount=1):
            self.inv.append(invitem(item, amount))
            return("success")

        def has_item(self, item, amount=1):
            if item in [i.item for i in self.inv]:
                if self.finditem(item).amount >= amount:
                    return(self.finditem(item).amount)
                else: return(False)
            else:
                return(False)

        def finditem(self, item):
            return(self.inv[[i.item for i in self.inv].index(item)])

        def remove_item(self, item, amount=1):
            if self.has_item(item):
                self.finditem(item).amount -= amount
                if self.finditem(item).amount <= 0:
                    self.inv.pop(self.inv.index(self.finditem(item)))
                    return ("gone")
                else:
                    return ("more left")
            else:
                return ("not found")
```

When I run this, the inventory display screen is first empty, and then the item appears in there like this:
[example run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2CV9.png)

Unfortunately, that 0 would be anything I put in there and I can't figure out how to add or subtract to ''amt'' during game play either by calling the item or trying to get the item to call an easily edited variable and display that as it's ''amt''.

This is the part where I'm supposed to tell you what all I've tried. This is tough for me, because I've tried so many variations of so many different things that I can't get into specifics of exactly what was typed. Essentially I played around with all the variations of interpolating the amt I could find through the documentation and other peoples' forum results and trying to make it work with my items, and mostly got a bunch of "class item doesn't have attribute amt" and "name amt is not defined". After that failed, i tried to convince my item to get its amt from a completely separate variable. I have successfully and easily used interpolated text to display the money on that inventory screen. it just asks for "text "money: [money].0" and changes easily during gameplay with $ money 1+10, etc. I just haven't been able to convince it to work properly if the interpolated information I'm trying to get from it is in an item class.

Thanks in advance for any ideas you may have about what i'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what went wrong! I needed to give my item class properties! This is what wound up working!

````
        def __init__(self, name, img, himg, amt):
            self.name = name
            self.img = img
            self.himg = himg
            self.amt = amt

        @property
        def output(self):
            return str(self.amt)

        def add_stack(self, amt):
            self. amt += 1

    class invitem(object):
        def __init__(self, item, amount):
            self.item = item
            self.amount = amount```
````